# Android, How to insert parameter from activity into JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, android

In my application I have an activity which acts as log-in form. After getting user id and password, i need to open a URL.

This web page includes log-in form (user id and password fields as well) and when user clicks on submit button, form processed by java-script function and form contents will be submitted to server.

However, I need to bypass showing this page and instead, loading URL, putting user id and password into parameters and calling doSubmit() function of JavaScript on behalf of user and finally getting server response.

I have user id and password but i don't know how to insert it into JavaScript. 
This is my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_loginweb);

        Log.i(TAG, "Try to create activity...");

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl(LOGINPAGE_URL);


        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");
    } 
}

public class JavaScriptInterface {
        Context mContext;

        /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
        JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        /** Show a toast from the web page */
        public void showToast(String toast) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your Javascript interface add some methods like this :

```
public String getUserId() {
        //return userId value here
    }

public String getPassword() {
        //return password value here
    }
```

From javascript side :

```
//Startup stuff
$(document).ready(function(e) { 
    var userId = Android.getUserId();
    var password = Android.getPassword();

  $("#idofuserIdField").val(userId);
$("#idofPasswordField").val(password);

//callSubmitFunctionHere
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm sure its impassible to ask them to add functions to their JS. because 1) they are bank and 2) with current JS, iPhone is done.

Comment: If I understood well, you want that the user fill out the userId and password from Java side (with EditText for example). Then they click on a button, and here it loaded a web page. From this point, this webPage is a connexion page and you want that connexion page to be automaticcaly filled out with what the user has just filled and then call automatically the submit function ?

Comment: correct. because it's fast process therefore user cannot see the second web log-in page.

Comment: I edited the answer then. Are you using jQuery ? (for the `val` method). I will do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I think one possible solution for that is using the HttpClient(apache-commons) and contact the server directly from your activity:

```
public static void login(String pUsername, String pPassword){
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

// Create a method instance.
GetMethod method = new GetMethod(YOUR_LOGIN_URL_WHICH_IS_CALLED_FROM_JS);

// Provide custom retry handler is necessary
method.getParams().setParameter(HttpMethodParams.RETRY_HANDLER, 
        new DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler(3, false));
method.setQueryString(new NameValuePair[] {      new NameValuePair("username", pUsername),new NameValuePair("password", pPassword)  });  

try {
  // Execute the method.
  int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);

  if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
    System.err.println("Method failed: " + method.getStatusLine());
  }

  // Read the response body.
  byte[] responseBody = method.getResponseBody();

  // Deal with the response.
  // Use caution: ensure correct character encoding and is not binary data
  System.out.println(new String(responseBody));

} catch (HttpException e) {
  System.err.println("Fatal protocol violation: " + e.getMessage());
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  System.err.println("Fatal transport error: " + e.getMessage());
  e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  // Release the connection.
  method.releaseConnection();
}}
```

Well, I think it is much more work than this(using SSL, Postparams and dealing with the result) but you find a lot of very helpful tutorials for that.